# verilog coding in modelsim

Tags: vlsi

[image: lATCH based clock gating]

can anyone tell me the verilog coding and simulation for this design using modelsim software..i had tried a lot by the following coding but i can't get the correct result..please i need it for my reference.

```
module SD_L(in,clk,rst,q,out);
  input in,clk,rst,q;
  output out;
  reg out;
  wire k1,k2,k3;
  assign k1=in||q;

  SD_dl m1(.enable(k1),.q(k2));

  assign k3=k2&clk;

  always@(posedge clk)
  begin
    out<=q;
  end

  SD_dff m2( .d(in),.clk(k3),.rst(rst),.out(q));

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You create k3 as "clk & k2", but then in your flip flop you have `always @ (posedge clk)` instead of `always @ (posedge k3)`.

Incidentally, as a design practice you should consider using a flip-flop with an enable signal instead of a gated clock.

Also, your schematic shows one latch and one flip-flop, while your Verilog apparently has three storage elements: one instantiated latch, one instantiated flip-flop, and one inferred flip-flop.

Answer (score 0):

as shown your circuit has some issues. In particular, a latch has 2 inputs and you only show 1.

a latch has an enable and a data input.

```
reg q;
wire d;

always @(latch_en or d) begin // corrected
   if (latch_en) q <= d;
end
```

also, is that an XOR gate or an OR gate? your diagram shows XOR, but your code shows OR.

Comment: A D latch should be `always @(en or d) if (en) q <= d;`

Comment: you are correct! brain-fart!